# mouseenter/leave & mouseover/out problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Script:

```
$( ".title").mouseenter(function() {
    var which = $(this).index();
    $('.globalnav li').find('.dropdown').hide().eq(which).show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var which = $(this).index();
    $('.globalnav li').find('.dropdown').hide().eq(which).hide();
});
```

Navigation:

```
<ul class="globalnav">
    <li>
        <div class="title"><a href="#" target="_self">Home</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="navlinks">
                <div class="linkstitle">Title</div>
                <div class="navlink"><a href="#" target="_self">Link1</a></div>
                <div class="navlink"><a href="#" target="_self">Link1</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
...
```

The above code is what I am using right now which does not work in Chrome as intended *I need to hold my click down to view the div.  I use mouseover, it does not work properly in IE and FF.

I am also having trouble showing the associated div of the title (on title hover, show specific div) due to the nature of the coding format itself (client given code). Right now, on hovering over a title, it shows the first li's content for "navlinks".

[**Here's a fiddle to show you**](http://jsfiddle.net/7QghX/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the index of the `.title` element, if the other LI's look like that, the `which` variable will always be `0`, and it's not the way to target the right `.dropdown` ?

Try something more like this

```
$( ".title").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var dropdown = $(this).closest('li').find('.dropdown').toggle(e.type=='mouseenter');

    $('.dropdown').not(dropdown).hide();
});
```

And if you want the dropdown to be visible while hovering it, place it inside the element that triggers the mouseleave

```
<li>
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#" target="_self">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="navlinks">
                <div class="linkstitle">Title</div>
                <div class="navlink"><a href="#" target="_self">Link1</a></div>
                <div class="navlink"><a href="#" target="_self">Link1</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2RHp7/10/)

Comment: The first one works like a charm, thanks! I'd +1 you but I don't have enough rep :( & do you know why I have to hold-click for it to work in chrome? Thanks so much!

Comment: Not sure, the index thing looks really wonky and strange, the solution in the answer above should work in all answers, but you have to change the HTML if you don't want the dropdown to dissapear when the mouse leaves the title element etc.